# ANDROID groovy.lang.MissingMethodException después de actualización de React Native

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle

Actualizé React native de acuerdo con la guía,
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.0&to=0.64.2
Al correr el comando "npx react-native run-android" o  "./gradlew clean" en la carpeta android me salió este error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\projects\CG\react_native_projects\find-here-advertiser\android\app\build.gradle' line: 196

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar.toPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: with(groovy.lang.Closure), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), with(boolean, groovy.lang.Closure), getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

No se qué es lo que está pasando o si me pueden recomendar en qué proyecto de github publicar esta pregunta, estaría agradecido.

android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

android\build.gradle

```
..........
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
........
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Opté por bajar la versión nuevamente de gradlew y funcionó perfectamente!!

Comment: Pon tu comentario como respuesta, y procura que sea detallada. Lee [answer], y también considera aceptar la respuesta,ya que el usuario "Comunidad" [se encarga de revivir la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452#1452) cada cierto tiempo.